# 'state is not defined' in Angular typescript controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am new to typescript and am trying to use `UI Router's $state` to navigate in my typescript controller. Unfortunately, I am still receiving a `state is not defined` error that I cannot resolve.

Here is my controller:

```
module MyApp {
export class LoginController {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    loginForm: any;
    state: any;

    constructor($state: ng.ui.IStateProvider) {
        this.state = $state;
    };

    login() {
        if (this.loginForm.$invalid) {
            return;
        }

        console.log(`Login was clicked, email is ${this.email} and password is ${this.password}`);
        state.go('Dashboard');
    }
}
}

angular.module('myApp').controller('loginController', MyApp.LoginController);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm using `Angular 1.5`

Answer (score 4):

You're assigning `$state` to `this.state` on controller construction.

This means that it should be referred as `this.state` all over the object.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `this.state` to access the `$state` variable inside login function. you can check below corrected implementation of your code.

[JSFiddle Typescript Implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/n4oj878s/)

```js
// Typescript

module MyApp {
  export class LoginController {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    loginForm: any;
    state: any;

    constructor($state: ng.ui.IStateProvider) {
      this.state = $state;
    };

    login() {

      if (this.loginForm.$invalid) {
        this.formError = "invalid form data";
        return;
      }

      this.formError = "";

      console.log(`Login was clicked, email is ${this.email} and password is ${this.password}`);
      this.state.go('Dashboard');
    }
  }
}

let app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      template: `
       <div ng-controller="loginController as lc">
          <form name="lc.loginForm" ng-submit="lc.login()">
            <div>Email:<input ng-model="lc.email" ng-required="true" /></div>
            <div>Password: <input ng-model="lc.password" ng-required="true" /></div>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="lc.login()">Click</button>
          </form>
        </div>      
      `
    })
    .state('Dashboard', {
      url: '/Dashboard',
      template: '<div> I am Dashboard </div>'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});

app.controller('loginController', MyApp.LoginController);
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```